# R Script for Optimizing Random Forest Training Set

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a training set (name: training) and a test set (name: test) with around six independent variables and one dependent variable.

One feature/independent variable in particular, which is categorical, is called 'lead_source'. There are around 30 unique lead sources. I would like to write a script that will go through each iteration of possible lead source combinations (from the training set) and spit out evaluation metrics (on the test set) for each Random Forest. The goal is to trim the 30 lead sources down into the best (5, 10, ..., n, etc.) that will have the most predictive power on the test set.

Unfortunately, I have no script experience so I am not sure where to start with this. The below code was the best I could do which is a script for running n trees. I've spent a tremendous amount of research online but couldn't find a solution that would help me.

Here is the random forest model I have built but am unable to run repeatedly  shuffling lead sources in and out of the training set:

```
library("randomForest")
training <- read.csv("training.csv")
RF <- randomForest(training[, -c(2,6)], training$Submitted, 
      sampsize=c(1000), do.trace=TRUE, importance=TRUE, ntree=500, 
      forest=TRUE)
testing <- read.csv("testing.csv")
pred <- data.frame(predict(RF, testing[ , -c(2,6)]))
names(pred) <- "Submitted"
write.csv(pred,file="LeadScoring.csv")

Headers: 
1 = 'State'
2 = 'Lead Source'
3 = 'Gender'
4 = '2 Digit Zip'
5 = 'Age Round'
6 (dependent variable) = 'Submitted'
```

Comment: That will be a lot combinations to try out. How about constructing a new feature called 'average target of category'. You could also merge categories having similar average targets. As target is used, a outer cross-validation is needed.